# How to set up consecutive CRON jobs

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

I am trying to setup a cron job to run two scripts. Here is what my command looks like right now:

```
55 15 * * 1-5 /bla/bla/bla/bla.sh && /bla/bla/bla/bla2.sh >> /bla/bla/bla/bla.log 2>&1
```

At 3:35pm monday-friday, this runs but for some reason the logs only prints the echo statements from the second file and not the first. However, output files from both scripts are being generated. This leads me to believe that for some reason the first script isn't being run properly. Any help figuring out how to run both one after the other and get logs appropriately would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirection has higher precedence than `&&`, so it's only being applied to the second command.

You need to group the commands so that the redirection applies to both of them.

```
55 15 * * 1-5 ( /bla/bla/bla/bla.sh && /bla/bla/bla/bla2.sh ) >> /../../../bla2.sh.crontab.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Why curly braces and not round ones?

Comment: Parentheses create a subshell, but there's no need for that here.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the process trees are the same both ways, so I changed it to parentheses.